# Developing Mac OS X virtual driver

Tags: macos, documentation, driver

I am looking forward to develop a driver (probably virtual) allowing to read audio streams within the computer (to modify MIDI streams actually), to send them to a software, after being analyzed by another part of the program.

The point is that, as much as I looked over Mac OS X documentation about drivers, I don't seem to find much practical information. I know that the Windows documentation is far better and much more explicit, but can I rely on that ?

So, do you have any information about virtual driver development on Mac OS X ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read about the IO kit, which is what you use to develop OSX drivers? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I did actually, but I'd rather have some practical situations. Or, at least, some informations outside of that documentation, if it exists, but thank you.

Comment: So what do you want to know - can you please be more specific?

Comment: I'd like to know if code samples exist in that domain, since I have to define the perimeter of work, and some questions like "Will it be multi-threaded" ? My point is that the information provided by the Apple documentation is more like a linux "man" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows drivers are likely to be very different from OSX.

OSX provides IOKit for drivers and has an IOAudioFamily interface, but I don't think it will be for MIDI. You may, however, be able to use the USB interface (IOUSBFamily) and go from there, assuming you're receiving the signals via a midi-USB cable.

The Apple docs aren't bad, but finding what's relevant is not so easy!

Developing a USB driver will involve creating a [Kernel Extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIntro/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000191-SW1) (Kext) in C++ and subclassing the appropriate interface, minimising the amount of code you'll have to write.

Once you've read that, [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html) for creating a device driver may be useful.

If you still don't like the Apple docs, I recommend getting the book "OSX and iOS Kernel Programming" by Halvorson & Clarke which, despite its title, is mostly concerned with developing drivers.

Comment: I already printed all that documentation, but I didn't read it all. Hopefully, I'll se some light about it. I'm taking your device on buying that book. Looks like very interesting, many thanks.